Is there a way to programmatically change screen size for tailwind class
I am building UI-kit with react tailwind.
I know that tailwind can't find classes that made with template strings. I want to achieve this:
I have a few components in my ui kit and I want them to have same logic (for i.e. button):
Button has variant size:{
sm: "p-1",
md: "p-2"
}
I want to automatically generate:
{
sm: "md:p-1",
md: "md:p-2"
}
And etc for all screen sizes.
Finally want to do smth like this:

<Button size="sm" md={size:"md"} />


I think I can't do this in function because tailwind couldn't see this classes in runtime.
Maybe there is a library or a way to do this in build time. I'm kinda lost cause I already tried a lot of things. Will be glad to see your answer
Tried twind, but can't really use it cause of deps conflicts

I'm not quite sure what effect you're trying to achieve. If you need to implement a responsive layout using media queries, wouldn't { small: "p-1 md:p-2", medium: "p-2 md:p-4" } meet your requirements?

No its not. If I would've had  { small: "p-1", medium: "p-2" , large: "p-3"}   and In one case I need small by default and medium in md screen in another small by default and large at md screen your suggestion not work in this scenario.

@АндрейНагорный Might I ask how would the small, medium and large to be defined in runtime? If they are manually defined, then why would you need to override the sm, md, etc. properties with tailwindcss?
